# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$token' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, java, android-asynctask, http-post

Передаю с телефона данные в PHP

```
   $title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$token = $_POST['token'];
  // ---- уведомление для трея ---- //
$payload = '{
  "to" : '$token',
  "notification" : {
    "title" : '$title',
    "body" : '$message',
    "sound": "notify"
  }
}';
```

Выдает ошибку

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$token' (T_VARIABLE)

С самого телефона передаю так

```
class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", token));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message_ban));

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return "Data Inserted Successfully";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Toast.makeText(ActivityAdmin.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(token, title, message_ban);
```

Как можно это исправить или хотя бы проверить,работает ли?

Comment: проверить - наверное, можно приложение запустить...

Comment: @michael_best, я ошибку ловлю в CMD_SHOW_LOG, при отправке данных из приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки исправил:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$token = $_POST['token'];
  // ---- уведомление для трея ---- //
$payload = "{
  to : '$token',
  notification : {
    title : '$title',
    body : '$message',
    sound : 'notify'
  }
}";
```

Вам надо было ошибку почитать, тогда стало ясно бы

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$token' (T_VARIABLE)

Вот этот токен шел после закрывающей кавычки, которая должна быть вложенной.

Comment: Понял,спасибо)Ошибка ушла,буду пытаться понять теперь,почему сообщение не доходит)

Comment: JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (') at position 6 а не подскажите что это за ошибка?Появилась после того,как ваш код использовал.

Comment: Поправил код, пробуйте

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p `json_encode()` `json_decode()` - не, не слышал

Comment: @LeonidMew `JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (t) at position 6`. но я так понимаю,это уже мои косяки где-то?
В `CMD_SHOW_LOG` выдает `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '\\'` на эту строку `$send .= 'Host: fcm.googleapis.com'."\r\n";`

Comment: Создайте json как @ArchDemon посоветовал. Про вторую ошибку не знаю. Может опять что-то с кавычками. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @LeonidMew честно говоря,я в этом не очень шарю(от слова совсем)По этому и спросил тут)Просто резко нужда в таком возникла...нашел пост на хабре,взял от туда код https://habr.com/post/345942/